# Is my MacBook Pro 2017 15" charging properly

Tags: mac, battery, macbook, macbook-pro

I am using Battery Health to measure how fast my MacBook Pro is charging. It says it is charging at 1.5 Watts which seems way to low. Is this about where it should be?

Yesterday it seemed like it was not charging very well because I could not leave the charger while using it as it stayed within ~2% of the charge it had before I plugged it in no matter how long I used it. I was using some heavy applications (Eclipse and a bunch of tabs) so that could have been a factor.

Here is it with the charger the mac came with

[image]

Here it is with the another apple charger but I use a different USB cable

[image]

Is all of this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, this is **Normal** behaviour.

When your charging level goes above a certain point (~90%), the wattage decreases to preserve the battery.

Comment: Once I am below like 50% what would normal wattage charge be considered?

Comment: The highest power charging adapters for your Macbook are rated for 87W. Realistically, I would say ~75 watts.